# MYSQL - Split the string "Lurex Cotton Squadrato" and return the last word

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I have a several rows in my table and I want to export the last word from one column into a new column.

Just need to split out the last word from this string, can't work out how to do it...

```
UPDATE sc_module_template_slideshows_images
SET image_title = RIGHT(image_name, ?????)
```

That's just a guess, any function would do. MYSQL 5.

Here's an example of my data set:

```
|| *slideshow_id* || *image_id* || *image_active* || *image_order* || *image_name* || *image_source* || *image_link* || *image_logo* || *image_title* || *image_presented* || *image_position* ||
|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || Lurex Cotton Lappato || media/products/Porcelain/Collections/Lurex/Swatches/Lurex Cotton Lappato.jpg ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
|| 1 || 2 || 1 || 2 || Lurex Cotton Squadrato || media/products/Porcelain/Collections/Lurex/Swatches/Lurex Cotton Squadrato.jpg ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
|| 2 || 3 || 1 || 3 || Lurex Flax Lappato || media/products/Porcelain/Collections/Lurex/Swatches/Lurex Flax Lappato.jpg ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
|| 2 || 4 || 1 || 4 || Lurex Flax Squadrato || media/products/Porcelain/Collections/Lurex/Swatches/Lurex Flax Squadrato.jpg ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
|| 3 || 5 || 1 || 5 || Lurex Lame Lappato || media/products/Porcelain/Collections/Lurex/Swatches/Lurex lame Lappato.jpg ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
|| 3 || 6 || 1 || 6 || Lurex Lame Squadrato || media/products/Porcelain/Collections/Lurex/Swatches/Lurex Lame Squadrato.jpg ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
|| 4 || 7 || 1 || 7 || Lurex Modal Lappato || media/products/Porcelain/Collections/Lurex/Swatches/Lurex Modal Lappato.jpg ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
|| 4 || 8 || 1 || 8 || Lurex Modal Squadrato || media/products/Porcelain/Collections/Lurex/Swatches/Lurex Modal Squadrato.jpg ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) is the correct function:

```
SET image_title = SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_name,' ',-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SET image_title = SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_name, ' ', -1);
```

Comment: Mootinator beat you by 4 seconds, but your answer was correct :)

Comment: i tested it before posting, that was my mistake.

Comment: @Richardakacyberwiki Aha!  I don't even have MySQL installed anywhere!  Can haz upvotes? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring_index() function.

Example

```
select substring_index('Lurex Cotton Lappato',' ',-1); -- Lappato
```

Apply it to update clause.